# Iterating through http response Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

So I'm very new to Angular2, and trying to iterate through http response I'm kindda stuck. With the following code :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._meetService.getAuth( "meets/"+ this.meetId + "/participants").subscribe(
      meet => {
        this.participants = meet.participants;
        this.organizators = meet.organizators;
        console.log(this.participants);
      },
      error => console.log("error")
    )
  }
```

I get values in both `this.participants` and `this.organizators` but with the following :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._meetService.getAuth("meets/"+ this.meetId + "/participants").subscribe(
      meet => {
        meet.participants.forEach(participant => this.members.push(participant));
        meet.organizators.forEach(organizator => this.members.push(organizator));
        console.log(this.members);
      },
      error => console.log("error")
    )
  }
```

I get the error logged. How can this be ?

Here the getAuth() method :

```
@Injectable()
export class MeetService {
  constructor(private http: Http, public api: ApiConfig, private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}

  getAuth(path: string) {
    var auth = this.api.headers();
    auth.append("X-Auth-Key", "azertyuiop...");
    return this.http.get(this.api.getPath(path), {headers: auth})
      .map(res => <any> res.json())
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the error which is getting logged?

Comment: post error log or error explanation.

Comment: also show `getAuth` method code..should have return `observable` object.

Comment: The error getting logged is the error from `error => console.log("error")`

Comment: whats the error you got ?

Comment: The error is "error" :D, but i expect that if the http call subscription hit an error, that means that the response code from the network call is not 200. Check the network tab and see if any request fails

Comment: Not at all, the request success with 200 status code. The ForEach() is pretty much the only thing separating one from the other

Comment: then check for `preview` tab is there any response is coming or not ?

Comment: Try to `console.log(error)` rather than `"error"`

Comment: Yep sorry about that. `Cannot read property push of undefined` is the error, even though I stated in my code `members: Array<any>`

Comment: Try to put `this.members = []` before you do `meet.participants.forEach(participant => this.members.push(participant));` See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are pushing to `this.members` which is `undefined`. Try to initialize it first

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._meetService.getAuth("meets/"+ this.meetId + "/participants").subscribe(
      meet => {
        this.members = [];
        meet.participants.forEach(participant => this.members.push(participant));
        meet.organizators.forEach(organizator => this.members.push(organizator));
        console.log(this.members);
      },
      error => console.log("error")
    )
  }
```

Setting `members: Array<any>` just tells TypeScript that there is a`member` property which should be of type `Array`, it does not create the property for you though.